# Have gulp to update references to angular views

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have an angular application which I am using gulp to build.

To keep my app code organized, I like to keep my directory structure grouped together by modules:

```
app
 -> modules
    -> sample
       - sample.js
       - sample.html
    app.js
```

So, in my angular app/modules/sample.js I reference the template

```
templateUrl: 'modules/sample/sample.html
```

I would like to keep this structure, but in my distribution, I would like my html moved to a views folder. I have a gulp task which does this

```
gulp.task('views', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/modules/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/views'))
        .pipe($.size());
});
```

However, this obviously breaks the references inside my javascript code. How would I use gulp to update the reference to 'views/sample/sample.html' in the javascript for distribution?

Comment: There's highly probably no built in module for that, you could maybe create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use gulp-replace to change the path in your JS files once you've compiled them for production. Pretty simple to use:

```
.pipe($.replace('app/modules/', 'dist/views/modules/'))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed just didn't know the right plugin. Thank you.